# "last directory" from url as string

Tags: r

I would like to return "blah".

```
url <- "https://www.example.com/apples/pears/blah.csv"
```

I can get blah but I feel like I'm writing more lines of code than I should. Example, to get blah.csv I can do:

```
url_split <- str_split(url, "/")
dirname <- url_split[[1]][length(url_split[[1]])]
```

This gives me "blah.csv", where I can do a very similar code block as above to get "blah" by calling str_split again.

Is there a more sophisticated one liner to get the last directory in the url minus ".csv"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fn <- basename("https://www.example.com/apples/pears/blah.csv")
gsub("\\..*$", "", fn)
```

Comment: Thanks that does the trick. What's going on here with basename() and also I'm struggling to read what the regex is doing? ```"\\..*$"```. I know it's reading from the end with $ but don;t see how it's getting the right bit

Comment: Enter the pattern at https://regex101.com/ and you'll get an explanation.

Comment: looking at [`?basename`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/basename) is relevant too.